# Laravel Multiple Record with single query not working

Tags: laravel

**General error: 1364 Field 'challen_student_id'** doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `challens` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2022-10-04 08:53:41, 2022-10-04 08:53:41))

```php
$students = Student::all('id');
$collection = collect($students)->map(function ($student) use($request) {
$collect = collect(['challen_student_id', 'challen_month', 'challen_due_date', 'challen_fine', 'challen_exam_fees', 'challen_status']);
    return $collect->combine([$student->id, $request->item['challen_month'], $request->item['challen_due_date'], $request->item['challen_fine'], $request->item['challen_exam_fee'], 'pending'])->toArray();
    // [enter image description here][1]
});
    
// print_r($collection->toarray());
// exit;
Challen::create($collection->toArray());
```

print_r result is

```php
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [challen_student_id] => 1
        [challen_month] => 
        [challen_due_date] => 
        [challen_fine] => 
        [challen_exam_fee] => 
        [challen_status] => pending
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Challen::insert($collection->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$students = Students::all();
foreach($students as $key => $value){
    Challen::create([
        'challen_student_id' => $value->id,
        'challen_month'      => $request->item['challen_month'],
        'challen_due_date'   => $request->item['challen_due_date'],
        'challen_fine'       => $request->item['challen_fine'],
        'challen_exam_fees'  => $request->item['challen_exam_fee'],
        'challen_status'     => 'pending'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a problem in your array structure it should be like this

`[{challen_student_id => 1 ,challen_month => '',challen_due_date => '' ,challen_fine => '' challen_exam_fee =>'' challen_status => 'pending'}]`

And always use NUllable fields when dealing with database it saves you many times
laravel provides nullable() function in migration